# No entra los datos al fichero

Tags: c++

**Cuando reviso, file1 no tiene datos en el**

File1 debería tener los datos que **respuesta** tiene al final de la ejecución

```
   fstream file1;
   fstream file2;
   FallaArchivo("Respuesta Anterior.txt");
   FallaArchivo("Respuesta.txt");
   file1.open("Respuesta Anterior.txt");
   file2.open("Respuesta.txt");
   cout<<"Dime tu pregunta"<<endl;
   string respuesta;
   string respuesta_anterior;
   getline(file1,respuesta_anterior);
   getline(file2,respuesta); 
       if(respuesta==respuesta_anterior){
           getline(file2,respuesta);
       }
       
   cout<<respuesta;
   file1<<respuesta;
}
```

Comment: SI es posible, coloca un código completo, que pueda ser ejecutado para reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder ejecutar el código he hecho lo siguiente:

1. He creado un nuevo proyecto en el que he colocado el siguiente código en un archivo (.cpp) en la función main:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       fstream file1;
       fstream file2;
       file1.open("Respuesta Anterior.txt");
       file2.open("Respuesta.txt");
       cout << "Dime tu pregunta" << endl;
       string respuesta;
       string respuesta_anterior;
       getline(file1, respuesta_anterior);
       getline(file2, respuesta);
       if (respuesta == respuesta_anterior) {
           cout << "Correcto" << endl;
           getline(file2, respuesta);
       }

       cout << respuesta;
       file1 << respuesta;

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Adicionalmente he creado dos archivos txt en la misma ubicación del archivo .cpp del proyecto con el contenido "hola" en ambos:
   [image]
3. Al ejecutar me ha dado este resultado:

   [image]

   Incluso al poner un breakpoint podemos consultar que "respuesta" y "respuesta_anterior" obtienen los valores correctamente:
   [image]

Por lo tanto en principio el código está bien, aún así si puedes consulta el contenido de las función "FallaArchivo" (o añádelo a la pregunta inicial) para comprobar que no es culpable del comportamiento inesperado, al igual del resto del código que creas que pueda afectar.

En última instancia recomiendo que revises el punto 2 que he mencionado ya que podría ser que los archivos no los hayas colocado en una ubicación que resulte accesible al programa al ejecutarse, para comprobar si es por esa razón podrías abrir la ruta absoluta en lugar de la relativa y así comprobar que no es este el problema, y si resulta ser ese el problema entonces te recomiendo que revises la configuración de Visual Studio (o IDE que estés usando) para ver si tiene acceso a la carpeta donde se encuentran dichos archivos